# Load spydata file

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I'm coming from R + Rstudio. In RStudio, you can save objects to an `.RData` file using [save()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html)

```
save(object_to_save, file = "C:/path/where/RData/file/will/be/saved.RData")
```

You can then [load()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html) the objects :

```
load(file = "C:/path/where/RData/file/was/saved.RData")
```

I'm now using Spyder and Python3, and I was wondering if the same thing is possible.

I'm aware everything in the globalenv can be saved to a `.spydata` using this :

[image: spyder save load spydata]

But I'm looking for a way to save to a `.spydata` file in the code. Basically, just the code under the buttons.

Bonus points if the answer includes a way to save an object (or multiple objects) and not the whole env.

(Please note I'm not looking for an answer using `pickle` or `shelve`, but really something similar to `R`'s `load()` and `save()`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) There's no way to do what you ask for with a command in Spyder consoles.

If you'd like to see this in a future Spyder release, please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) about it, so we don't forget to consider it.

Comment: As of August 2018, is it still not possible to load the saved 'spydata' in Spyder?

Comment: @Antonio, no, there isn't, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So are there any workarounds for this problem? I do need to be able to save and load the outputs and I really do not want to switch from Spyder to another IDE! Maybe there are some commands in Ipython through which I can save/load my outputs?

Comment: No, there are no workarounds in Spyder, sorry. Perhaps there is a command in IPython to do this but I'm not aware of it, sorry again.

Comment: oh no worries at all! I appreciate the response.

Comment: As of October 2019, is still seems there no way to load spydata with a command.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comment [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13601#issuecomment-678594561), we can

1. rename the file from `.spydata` to `.tar`
2. extract the file (using file manager, for example). It will deliver a file `.pickle` (and maybe a `.npy`)
3. extract the objects saved from the environment:

import pickle

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:

    data_temp = pickle.load(f)
```

4. that object will be a dictionary with the objects saved.